# Assembly Load Error - "Could not load file or assembly 'DeathByCaptcha

Tags: c#

I am using DeathByCaptcha dll in C#.net which O got from DeathByCaptcha Site
and in My Code I am Adding this dll in references by using Add Reference.
But I am getting following error. Can anyone solve my issue?

> Main has thrown an exception

```
Source: Captch

Message: Could not load file or assembly 'DeathByCaptcha, Version=1.0.6612.28025, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Exception Type: FileNotFoundException

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'DeathByCaptcha, Version=1.0.6612.28025, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'DeathByCaptcha, Version=1.0.6612.28025, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at DeathExample.Captch.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.ActivityInstance.Execute(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Comment: When your program is launched the system canno't find the .dll or one of its dependencies either in your path and in the launch directory. You can check the dependencies of that .dll using http://www.dependencywalker.com/ and see what it's missing.

Comment: after adding referece, did you rebuild your solution. And output directory is expected to contain that dll, is it available in o/p directory ?

Comment: The error is self explanatory _Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies_ means you need to check if all dependencies are also in the same folder.

Comment: In the references, right click and select properties.  Set CopyLocal to true for the dll.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies but nothing works for mi.....

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the DeathByCaptcha dll.  Nothing I would do or change could get this to build.  Then I happened to do a build on a different machine and it worked.  I assumed the problem was resolved, but later on when trying to do a build on the original machine I ran into the same problem.  That's when I realized it was probably the machine environment.  Turns out that line of thinking was correct.  You need to open up the properties on the DeathByCaptcha.dll and unblock it.  This resolved my issue.

[image]